# What aircraft is this and to which air force does it belong?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, fighter

[image: Fighter]

[image: twinEngineSingleStabilozer]

Hi, could someone identify the type of this fighter jet and the air force which operates it? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Panavia Tornado, Royal Air Force (UK), 13 Squadron.**

The aircraft in the question is identified as belonging to No. 13 Squadron by the distinctive green, yellow and black 'Squadron flash' painted on the aircraft side  below the front part of the cockpit.

[image]

Royal Air Force roundel

[image]

13 Squadron flash

[image: A Tornado of No. 13 Squadron as seen at the 2007 CIAF air show in the Czech Republic]

Above: a Tornado of No. 13 Squadron as seen at the 2007 CIAF air show in the Czech Republic. The squadron flew Tornado GR.1A aircraft from 1990, and later the GR.4 and GR.4A variants.

Here is ZA401 (a GR.4) at RAF Leuchars in 2005 with the 13 Sqn flash painted on the tail as well as the normal place, as part of the Squadron's 90th anniversary celebrations:

[image]

[No. 13 Squadron RAF (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No._13_Squadron_RAF)

Comment: Many squadrons have used this plane (9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 27, 31, 45, 75, 617), but are you sure about 13? It seems to be one of the few that hasn’t?

Comment: @Tim - 13 Sqn operated Tornados from 1990 to 2011, first from Honington and then in 1994 moved to Marham.

Comment: I never liked them much when they were in service, but now they are gone, I feel a bit nostalgic about Tornados. I think ZA401 looks nice above.

Comment: ahh so they did. Strange the page on the Tornado misses that off. I wonder if it’s because of the disbanding / reformation

Answer (score 9):

That is a Panavia Tornado operated by the UK Royal Air Force.

[image: photo of Tornado]

You can tell by the shape of the nose wheel door, and the rear of it has a characteristic boxy shape with the stabilators lower than the wing. The roundel is the RAF low visibility roundel.

Comment: The shape of the nose is characteristic.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey characteristic of the Tornado IDS, bomber-striker, while the Tornado ADV interceptor had a longer nose.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey why is it’s nose so *pointy*? It’ll poke somebody’s eye out!

Comment: You can also narrow it down by being twin-engine and flown by the RAF.  The other twin-engine options are the Canberra, Lightning, Buccaneer or Typhoon, all of which have *very* distinctive shapes which this clearly is not.